# Android app bug: A Spanish question shows up on my feed

Tags: support, android-app, languages, android-app-feed

I don't speak Spanish, therefore I shouldn't see non-English questions unless I explicitly chose to. A question from es.SO shows up on my feed, the third one in the image below.

[image]

There should be a control over what categories and languages to see. At least filter out languages for non speakers.

Comment: there are about 12 different SE sites talking about none english language,4 none english.SO and about 8 like french language and latin and so on. If each site would have a hot question on my feed. the feed would be a mess

Comment: Latin's a bad example: although some titles there contain *some* Latin, almost all of the titles currently on the front page are predominantly English, and make at least as much sense as, say, the question titles on movies.stackexchange.com (which often need the tags to provide sufficient context).

Comment: @PeterTaylor sorry I haven't visited that, i was counting them only from SE